# validate textbox if empty and if number entered

Tags: c#, java

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (txtfname.Text == "" )
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Please enter your First Name");
      txtfname.Focus();
   }
}
```

I want to validate a textbox such that a person cannot leave it blank nor can they add numbers.  Do I have to write an "else if" statement or is there any operator that I can use to put it all in the same if statement.

Comment: go and read a book about c#, and about logical operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfname.Text) ||
        txtfname.Text.Any(c => Char.IsNumber(c)) ) {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your First Name");
        txtfname.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,it's really useful but can you explain me the part (c => Char.IsNumber(c)

Comment: It basically checks if `Any` character `c` in the string is a number or not.

Answer (score 4):

The operator you can use is [`||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string fName = txtfname.Text;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fName) || fName.Any(Char.IsDigit))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter your First Name without digits");
    txtfname.Select();
}
```