# System.FormatException error and how to check if form is empty?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

***Overview of Project:***

A have been writing a `SaveDetails() function` which takes all user `input` from a number of `Textboxes` and stores it in my private Fields. The function needs to first check that all validation is successful, if true, the values need to be stored within, the newly created instance. If fail, a message needs to display to the user that there is an error.

```
private void btn_SaveDetails_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

                foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls) // Loop through all controls 
                {
                    if (errorProvider1.GetError(c).Length > 0)   // Look for errorProviders
                    {
                        isValid = false;                         // if Found, change Var to False 
                        MessageBox.Show("invalid entry, please revisit the form before proceding");   //Display Error Mesage

                    }
                }
                if (isValid)
                {
                    FormValidation formValidation = new FormValidation(ID);
                    // takes Id on contrructs
                    buttonPresed = "Ok was Pressed!!";

                    formValidation.RName = txt_RegisteredName.Text;
                    formValidation.SName = txt_ShortName.Text;
                    formValidation.BName = txt_BuildingName.Text;
                    formValidation.BNumber = (int)nud_BuildingNumber.Value;
                    formValidation.StreetName = txt_StreetName.Text;
                    formValidation.Locality = txt_Locality.Text;
                    formValidation.Town = txt_Town.Text;
                    formValidation.County = txt_County.Text;
                    formValidation.Country = txt_Country.Text;
                    formValidation.Postcocde = txt_Postcode.Text;
                    formValidation.AltSwitch = int.Parse(txt_SwitchBoard.Text);
                    formValidation.Fax = int.Parse(txt_Fax.Text);
                    formValidation.Email = txt_Email.Text;
                    formValidation.ButtonType = buttonPresed;

                    MessageBox.Show("Indi Form Saved");
                    Hide();


                }
            }

            catch (Exception b)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());
            }
        }



    }
```

I am currently experiencing two issues,

**1st ). Query:**

if the user does not enter any values and clicks save on a “Empty form”, no ErrorProviders would have been Flagged, so the function is unaware of an incomplete form.  I need to check if nothing has been entered into TextBoxes which is on a panel. Is there a way to do this and check if my form empty? Is there a method of checking if all controls on a panel are null?

**2nd). Query**

I’m also  getting the exception of `System.FormatException`: Input string was not in correct Format.  I know this is due to me inputting a string into this conversion. 
 I’m taking my input from a `TextBox` and hence the conversion. This exception occurs when entering anything, except Int e.g  so +, h ~ whitespace would all fail and give me this exception. If any ideas of possible solutions ? I’ve tried `tryParse` however this seemed to not convert the input string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way of testing if any textbox is empty

```
TextBox[] boxes = {
   txt_RegisteredName,
   txt_ShortName,
   txt_BuildingName,
   txt_StreetName,
   txt_Locality,
   txt_Town,
   txt_County,
   txt_Country,
   txt_Postcode,
   txt_SwitchBoard,
   txt_Fax,
   txt_Email
};
Boolean isEmpty = boxes.Where(x => x.Text.Trim().Length == 0).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Query 1:
[validate textbox if empty and if number entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157365/validate-textbox-if-empty-and-if-number-entered)

For Query 2: Which text box is failing? what is datatype and what are you trying to pass exactly?

Comment: All my of my textBoxes which require values of Int  int.Parse(txt_SwitchBoard.Text); int.Parse(txt_Fax.Text);

Comment: you mean you want to pass an int value from text box to your program? @whatdoyouNeedFromMe

Comment: have you tried  int yourvariable= int.Parse(txtboxname.Text); @whatdoyouNeedFromMe

Comment: also check if empty value is being passed to your variable this also result in System.FormatException @whatdoyouNeedFromMe